# Tensor product of a sheaf of module and a residue field

Tags: algebraic-geometry, tensor-products, sheaf-theory

Let $S$ be a scheme over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ and $\mathcal{L}$ an invertible sheaf on $S$.

In Pink's article ([here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.02432), see section 1.4 on page 13), he states that:

For any section $\ell\in \mathcal{L}(S)$ and any point $s\in S$ we let $\ell(s)\in \mathcal{L}\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_S}k(s)$ denote the value of $\ell$ over the residue field $k(s)$ of $s$.

My question is: what is the definition of $\mathcal{L}\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_S}k(s)$?

We know we can define the tensor product of two $A$-modules or of two $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules, but what is the tensor product of an $\mathcal{O}_X$-module and a field?

Comment: I'd say restrict $\mathcal{L}$ to a small enough $U\ni s$ to get $\mathcal{L}(U)$ a (free) module over the standard ring $O_X(U)$ containing the point in its $Spec$, then look at $\mathcal{L}(U)\otimes_{O_X(U)}O_{X,s}/p_s$

Comment: Dear Alan, you are absolutely right: it  makes no sense to take the tensor product of an $\mathcal{O}_X$-Module and a field.

Answer (score 4):

The notation $\ell(s)\in \mathcal{L}\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_S}k(s)$ does not make sense.
It is an abuse of language for the correct description $$\ell(s)\in \mathcal{L}_s\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{S,s}}k(s)=\mathcal{L}_s/\mathfrak m_{S,s} \mathcal{L}_s$$  (Where of course $\mathfrak m_{S,s}$ is the maximal ideal of the local ring $\mathcal O_{S,s}$)

Answer (score 2):

Georges' answer (the other one) is more general and more common than the following, but this does still show up sometimes:

Here $k(s)$ can refer to the skyscraper sheaf with stalk $k(s)$ at the point $s$ and stalk $0$ everywhere else, especially when $s$ is a closed point. It is easy to check that this is an $\mathcal{O}_X$-module: we define the action by $f\in \mathcal{O}_X(U)$ on $k(s)(U)$ to be the $0$ action on the $0$ module if $s\notin U$ and to be multiplication by the image of $f$ under the composite map $\mathcal{O}_X(U)\to\mathcal{O}_{X,s}\to \mathcal{O}_{X,s}/\mathfrak{m}_s \cong k(s)$ otherwise.

Comment: I am a little confused about this definition.
A skyscraper sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$ is:
(1) [Hartshorne or Stacks Project] Let $x\in X$ be a point. Then $\mathcal{F}_P=A$ for some abelian group $A$ and for all $P\in \overline{\{ x \}}$ and $\mathcal{F}_P=0$ otherwise.
(2) [Qing Liu] There exists a finite set of closed points such that the stalks of $\mathcal{F}$ at those closed points are $A$ and $0$ otherwise.
Now back to the original setting.
Not all points $s\in S$ are closed, so we cannot define the skyscraper sheaf $k(s)$ whose stalks vanishing everywhere except at $s$.

Comment: You're right, this interpretation is only valid for the case of closed $s$. Georges' answer is more general and more common (and probably should be accepted), but this interpretation does still show up sometimes - and indeed it was the first place my mind went when I saw the question.

Comment: Ok, I got the point. Thank you for answering my question twice.

Comment: Can I say given a sheaf on $X$, say $F$, then $F\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}k(x)=F_x\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}}k(x)$?

Comment: @6666 This is an abuse of notation/language which is somewhat common - often, when people say the LHS of what you wrote, they really mean the RHS. This is exactly covered by Georges' answer above, and there is no need for you to get confirmation from me as to this fact. Please consider whether you're contributing to the discussion before commenting.